# Access Bluetooth Device from ListView

Tags: android, bluetooth

Here is my code.

---

```
//Get Bonded Devices
pbluetoothdevice = mbluetoothadapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pbluetoothdevice.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pbluetoothdevice){
            list.add(bt.getName()+"\n"+bt.getAddress());
        }
    }
    else
        msg("NO Paired Device Found!");
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    //Connect to the device.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(/*BluetoothDevice to be passed*/);
            connectThread.start();
        }
    });
```

I wish to connect to the bluetooth device in the  `OnItemClickListner()`, I have made a Thread in which I am gonna pass the BluetoothDevice. How Should I go about?

Answer (score 1):

Get address of device and connect to it:

```
   // Get the device MAC address
    String address = <address of bluetooth device>//it can be get from your device object
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    // Attempt to connect to the device
    mChatService.connect(device, secure);    //secure: Security type - Secure (true) , Insecure (false)
```

you can refer [android sample](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatFragment.html#l370).